# HTML5 error on page meta refresh with random value (forces refresh)

Tags: html, refresh, meta

In my code I have refresh tag to force a refresh every 60 seconds to show the new data pulled from the database. But since converting to HTML 5 I get the following error. Any idea how to fix this?

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60;url=ttheview.jsp?zone=alldata&amp;random=OP6JWUAT7A#zone-alldata"/>
```

Error: Bad value 60;url=thepageview.jsp?zone=alldata&random=OP6JWUAT7A#zone-alldata for attribute content on element meta: Expected a space character, but saw u instead.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Funny, I got a down vote on my question, yet I see it just won a "most popular question" badge.

Comment: Funny, but the W3C example shows no space:
http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html

Comment: Nice catch, W3C may have been where I got some code samples from.

Comment: Bootstrap gives no space! ((confused))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Expected a space character, but saw u instead.

Did you try adding a space before url?

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60; url=ttheview.jsp?zone=alldata&amp;random=OP6JWUAT7A#zone-alldata"/>
```

Comment: Would you have a clue as to why many provide examples without spaces? (I.E.: Bootstrap)

Comment: As I recall, the original example I ever saw didn't have the space, so it is copy and paste over and over again.